# Why can't I turn off vibrate while keeping audio on when a e-mail comes in?

Tags: email, notifications, audio, vibration

After my Galaxy Nexus upgraded itself to Jelly Bean last night, my phone refuses to turn vibrate off! It's set to Vibrate Never when email arrives, but it vibrates anyway. I've restarted the phone, taken the battery out, etc, but it still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Mine too. I got this behavior to change by doing the following:

1. Open the Gmail app.
2. In the menu, select "Settings"
3. Select your Gmail account.
4. Select "Sound & Vibrate"
5. Set the Sound to "Silent", and the Vibrate to "Never"

This fixed it for me. My guess is that it is a bug or poor design (the Sound option seems to override the Vibrate option).

Comment: I'd like to keep the audio on but the vibrate off though :(